# 'int' object is not subscriptable error while trying to classify my data

Tags: python, numpy

while coding in pycharm i got this error: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
and don't know how to get rid of it.
this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def AF(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1


Q1 = 3
Q2 = 1

Xi = ([[-1, -1], [0, 1], [1, -1], [0, 0]])
T = np.concatenate((np.ones((1, Q1)), -1 * np.ones((1, Q2))), axis=1)
T = np.squeeze(T)
W1 = np.zeros(2)
W2 = np.ones(2)
b1 = 0
b2 = 0
N = Q1 + Q2
k = 0

for i in range(4):
    net1=np.matmul(W1,Xi[i])+b1
    y1=AF(net1)
    net2=np.matmul(W2,y1[i])+b2
    if AF(net2)!= T[i]:
        if T[i]==1:
            J=np.argmax(net1)
            b[J] = b[J]+ (1-net1[J])
            W[i,J] = W[i,J]+Matmul((1-net1[J]), Xi[i,J])
        elif T[i]==-1:
            for K in range(3):
                b[K] = b[K] + (-1 - net2[k])
                W[i, K] = W[i, K]+Matmul((-1-net2[K]), Xi[i, K])
       #xx1 = np.arange(-3, 3)
       #xx2 = (-b - W[0] * xx1) / W[1]
       #print('Weight=', W, 'Bias=', b)
       plt.plot(Xi[T == -1, 0], Xi[T == -1, 1], 'go')
       plt.plot(Xi[T == 1, 0], Xi[T == 1, 1], 'r^')
       plt.plot(xx1, xx2, 'g')
```

and i get this error:

```
  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

please help me solving this error!

Comment: post full traceback of your error and also solve indentation problem at `def AF(x):
`

Comment: Please fix your indentation - whitespace matters

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
net2 = np.matmul(W2, y1[i]) + b2
```

you try to subscript `y1`, which is the result of `y1 = AF(net1)`, which always returns an `int`.